# Jackson in Spring: how to unmarshal a "generic" class w/o it thinking it's a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: json, spring, jackson

So my entities look like this:

```
public class HappyClass<T>
{
    private String id;
    prviate int ver;
    private Object obj;

    public String getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId( String id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVer()
    {
        return this.ver;
    }

    public void setVer( int ver )
    {
        this.ver = ver;
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo( use = Id.NONE )
    public T getObj()
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj( T obj )
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

public class HappyGeneric
{
    private String someStuff();

    public String getSomeStuff()
    {
        return this.someStuff();
    }

    public void setSomeStuff( String someStuff )
    {
        this.someStuff = someStuff;
    }
}
```

If I instantiate a class like this:

```
HappyClass<HappyGeneric> hc = new HappyClass<HappyGeneric>();
```

If I send it to Spring in a `@ResponseBody` it returns this:

```
{
    "id" : "iamsomeid",
    "ver" : 123,
    "obj" : {
        "someStuff" : "iamsomestuff"
    }
}
```

However, when Spring and/or Jackson attempts to unmarshal the same JSON, it figures out that the main class is a `HappyClass`, however, the `getObj()` it unmarshals to a `LinkedHashMap` and *not* a `HappyGeneric` no matter what I seem to annotate it with.

Anybody have any ideas how I can force Jackson to unmarshal that generic to the original class?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm aware I can call `mapper.convertValue( blah.getObj(), HappyGeneric.class )` and get the object out that way-- I was hoping to get Spring to figure it out automatically (through annotations, for example).

Comment: `Id.NONE` makes no sense here; it means you are disabling inclusion of type information (almost as if you didn't even add `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation).

Comment: Removing `Id.NONE` didn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you use some other type, there definitely should be type information included in JSON (and your example does not show anything inside `obj`). Which version of Jackson is this with?